# Pandas standard deviation miracle

Tags: pandas, standard-deviation

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [861166021755746, 861166021755746, 861166021755746]})
print(df.describe())
```

Here is the output (please note the value of std):

```
Test
count  3.000000e+00
mean   8.611660e+14
std    1.186328e+07
min    8.611660e+14
25%    8.611660e+14
50%    8.611660e+14
75%    8.611660e+14
max    8.611660e+14
```

The correct value of std is zero, since all three numbers are the same.

Now I take my dataframe above and replace first digit 8 with digit 9

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Test': [961166021755746, 961166021755746, 961166021755746]})
print(df.describe())
```

And the output now is (please note std number):

```
Test
count  3.000000e+00
mean   9.611660e+14
std    0.000000e+00
min    9.611660e+14
25%    9.611660e+14
50%    9.611660e+14
75%    9.611660e+14
max    9.611660e+14
```

Did I find magical number or what is going on?

Comment: I think it is probably the same as this issue?  https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/10242  I would use numpy std.  Note that your numbers are in the rough vicinity of the maximum precision of the mantissa for a double precision number.

Comment: From that issue, if you install `bottleneck` it will also solve it.

Comment: `bottleneck` is numpy library. As far as I understand numpy already computes everything correctly. I don't see how `bottleneck` will fix pandas?

Comment: `bottleneck` is an optional depedency that that `pandas` will use for speedups if installed - in this case it also uses a different `var` algo that doesn't have same stability problems from that issue.  see - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#recommended-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was indeed a bug related to variance miscalculations and has been resolved in version `0.17.0`. If you use any of the previous versions, you should update it to a newer version or as suggested in the comments install `bottleneck` in your environment.